# How to know if there are updates available?

Tags: apt, updates, bash, php

I am running a 12.04 LTS ubuntu server. And I think it would be nice if I could be informed when updates are available. But I can't find how to know...

I have tried looking at `apt-get` man page. From it I was able to use `apt-get -s upgrade` to get the apt-get output in a script without blocking on questions.

Now, I clearly see the différence :

**Updates are available :**

```
apt-get -s upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dpkg dpkg-dev libdpkg-perl
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst dpkg [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.2] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Conf dpkg (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [amd64])
Inst dpkg-dev [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.2] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all]) []
Inst libdpkg-perl [1.16.1.2ubuntu7.2] (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all])
Conf libdpkg-perl (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all])
Conf dpkg-dev (1.16.1.2ubuntu7.3 Ubuntu:12.04/precise-updates [all])
```

**Updates are not available :**

```
apt-get -s upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But I don't know how to proceed from there. How can I tell, from a bash script (or php script) that there are updates available or not ?

Edit :

**Here is my current bash code. It does not work.**

```
updates_available=`/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`

if [ "${updates_available}" = "0 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates." ];
then
   echo "No updates are available"
else
   echo "There are updates available"
fi
```

Comment: Well it's only going to say `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` if there are not updates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read the man pages for 
[`motd(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/motd.5.html), 
[`pam_motd(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pam_motd.8.html) and 
[`update-motd(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/update-motd.5.html).
 On my system, `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available` invokes `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` which displays this when I log in:

```
19 packages can be updated.
12 updates are security updates.
```

---

Delving a little deeper, the "...-updates-available" script invokes `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable`. If you read that (python), you'll see that if you omit the human readable flag, it will output "19;12" to stderr. We can grab that with this:

```
IFS=';' read updates security_updates < <(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)
echo $updates
echo $security_updates
```

```
19
12
```

Now you can say:

```
if (( updates == 0 )); then
    echo "No updates are available"
else
    echo "There are updates available"
fi
```

Comment: I can go with that and test `if [ `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available` = "0 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates." ]; then ... fi`

Comment: Unfortunately,the check doesn't work (I added the forgotten quotes in my previous reply.) I suspect something to do with the new lines. I have updated my post with the code I derived from your reply.

Comment: refined answer.

Comment: Awesome answer, @glennjackman . I was going to answer with https://www.google.com/search?q=apt-get+check+if+updates+are+available #ImNotHelpfulToday =)